# How to create a nx library with angular services

Tags: nrwl-nx

I have a couple of Angular apps running in an nx workspace. All these apps are using Angular Material Dialogs. For that I usually create Angular services like that:

```
import { AdministrationComponent } from '@workspace/shared/administration';
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  export class ContentService {
    openAdministration(): MatDialogRef<AdministrationComponent> {
      return this.dialog.open(AdministrationComponent, {...});
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Because all apps should have the possibility to open the Administration Dialog, I move the AdministrationComponent and the AdminService to an angular library:

```
nx generate @nx/angular:library administration --directory=libs/shared --simpleName --standalone
nx generate @nx/angular:library adminService --directory=libs/shared --simpleName
```

When I use nx serve app, everything works fine. The issue is that when I try to build the application, I'm facing the following error:

> error TS6059: File
> '.../workspace/libs/shared/administration/src/index.ts' is not under
> 'rootDir' '.../workspace/libs/shared/adminService/src'. 'rootDir' is
> expected to contain all source files.

When I remove the import within the service (line one), it is working again. It looks like, that I can't import any other library into my library (which should be a common approach).

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have the @workspace/shared/administration mapped to the good directory in your tsconfig.base.json ?
2. Could be the index.ts with wrong export in your lib.
3. Could come from compilerOptions in your tsconfig.

My config is like :
"compilerOptions": {
"rootDir": ".",

rootDir should be the highest level directory.

Source/Doc:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir